# Simplify the repetitive line using case statement ruby

Tags: ruby, case

```
case params[:application]
  when "cbeweb"
    token = CognifySession.find_or_create(user).access_token
  when "idweb"
    token = ComposeSession.find_or_create(user).access_token
  else
    token = Session.find_or_create(user).access_token
end
```

As you can see it is very repetitive since `find_or_create(user).access_token` is keep appearing. In ruby what is the beset way to remove most of that repetition of `token = {class name}.find_or_create(user).access_token`

Comment: Use a map of application id (or whatever you call it) to classes.

Answer (score 4):

Move that repeating code outside of the class selection logic.

```
klass = {
  "cbeweb" => CognifySession,
  "idweb" => ComposeSession,
}.fetch(params[:application], Session)

token = klass.find_or_create(user).access_token
```

Answer (score 1):

Although this answer is not much different from [the answer of Sergio Tulentsev](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62837764/3982562). I would like to add a implementation suggestion. Since you seemingly use this in a Rails controller.

If you need this in multiple controllers and/or multiple times in the same controller, consider adding a private method that retrieves this class.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  SESSION_CLASSES = {
    'cbeweb' => CognifySession,
    'idweb'  => CognifySession,
  }
  SESSION_CLASSES.default = Session
  SESSION_CLASSES.freeze

  private

  def session_class
    # Assuming this is always based upon the params[:application] value.
    # If not, pass the string as method parameter instead.
    SESSION_CLASSES[params[:application]]
  end
end
```

```
class SomeController < ApplicationController
  def some_action
    token = session_class.find_or_create(user).access_token
  end
end
```